# How do I exclude categories from get_tags?

Tags: tags

I have this function

```
$tags = get_tags( array('exclude' => 11, 12) )
```

Which excludes specific tags 11 and 12. But without manually having to add each tag **ID** I don't want shown, how do I exclude the category that these tags are coming from?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't get it. Could you maybe rephrase your problem somehow?

Comment: note that asking the database to exclude the tag for you is going to be very expensive/slow. It's much easier, and significantly faster, to ask for all the tags then do an `if` statement to skip over those 2 tags

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time wording this question: Rather than specifying and manually adding tag id's to exclude from a category, is there a way to just add a category so that all tags from that category aren't shown? I hope that makes more sense...

Comment: You need a way to mark tags in admin, which will be automatically hidded on front-end, right?

Comment: Tags don't belong to categories. They're just attached to posts. So no, here isn't a way to provide a category to exclude because tags and categories aren't related ike that. If you have multiple sets of tags that you use differently for posts in different categories, then you'd be better off created a separate taxonomy.

Answer (score -1):

Since this question is too hard to ask, I'm going to use custom taxonomies. Thanks for your help so far, everyone.

Answer (score -1):

You could get all of the term IDs for the `badcategory` and use those in your exclude filter:

```php
$bad_terms = get_terms( [ 'taxonomy' => 'badcategory', 'fields' => 'ids' ] );
$good_tags = get_tags( [ 'exclude' => $bad_terms ] );
```

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. This code won't do anything. Tags can't belong to another taxonomy, so excluding specific categories from `get_tags()` doesn't make any sense. They're already not going to be included.